# Android: Get http content after the page refresh

Tags: android, http, refresh, okhttp

I have a webpage, e.g. http://abc.xyz that has a default loading text before it's fully processed with server-side script.

```
Loading...
```

And after around 2 seconds, the server finishes processing the get request and generates the new content

```
New content
```

I use [OKHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) for `http://abc.xyz` but can only get the `Loading...` text.

```
 val client = OkHttpClient()

 val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .URL("http://abc.xyz")
        .build()
 client.newCall(request).enqueue(this)
```

How can I get the content after it is processed?

Comment: Why is this question tagged php while the content doesn't involve php at all?

Comment: Removed the PHP tag

Comment: Could you plz add more details instead of removing tag. For example, how does the server respond to requests and return different responses? How do you use OKHttpClient? and other contexts that help describe the question clearly.

Comment: Added the sample code. Thanks